# Sum values across number of date periods

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of products, defined by PRODUCT_ID, along with a selection of periods. The periods are not related to each product, but there are multiples periods which may or may not overlap. This table is called MY_PRODUCTS_BY_PERIOD

Below is an example of the data I have now;

[image: Data, product by periods]

I have another table that lists sales of all products, by day, by PRODUCT_ID. This table is called MY_TABLE_OF_SALES_DATA below.

I wish to obtain the sum of all sales of these products for the different periods, using my table of sales data. An example of what I am trying to achieve is below;

[image: sum of sales by period]

The issue I am having is creating a succinct way to summarise sales for each of the periods, whilst also avoiding double-counting sales where the periods overlap for certain products.

I have attempted using the below code to sum for each period:

```
SELECT PREPERIODSTART, PREPERIODEND, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND, POSTPERIODSTART, POSTPERIODEND
     ,SUM(case
             when MS.DAY_DATE BETWEEN PREPERIODSTART and PREPERIODEND
               then MS.CASH_SALES
             else 0
           end) SUM_PRE_SALES
     ,SUM(case
             when MS.DAY_DATE BETWEEN PERIODSTART and PERIODEND
               then MS.CASH_SALES
             else 0
           end) SUM_PROMO_SALES
     ,SUM(case
             when MS.DAY_DATE BETWEEN POSTPERIODSTART and POSTPERIODEND
               then MS.CASH_SALES
             else 0
           end) SUM_POST_SALES          
FROM MY_TABLE_OF_SALES_DATA MS
INNER JOIN MY_PRODUCTS_BY_PERIOD SP
ON MS.PRODUCT_ID = SP.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY PREPERIODSTART, PREPERIODEND, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND, POSTPERIODSTART, POSTPERIODEND
ORDER BY PREPERIODSTART, PREPERIODEND, PERIODSTART, PERIODEND, POSTPERIODSTART, POSTPERIODEND
```

However there is something wrong with the result, with sales for identical periods being different. See the below example;

[image: incorrect answer]

Note that both rows have the same preperiod length, yet different total sales.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Is this possible that hours and minutes in table MY_PRODUCTS_BY_PERIOD are different for the same days?